Amazon SP API Invalid 'marketplaceIds' provided
I'm using Electron and try to use the Amazon SP SPI. Somehow I always get the following error despite that my marketplaceIds are correct.
// apiCall.js
const SellingPartner = require("amazon-sp-api");
require('dotenv').config({ path: './api.env' });

function apiCall(eanNumbers) {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const spClient = new SellingPartner({
                region: "eu",
                refresh_token: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
                credentials: {
                    SELLING_PARTNER_APP_CLIENT_ID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
                    SELLING_PARTNER_APP_CLIENT_SECRET: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
                },
            });
            let res = await spClient.callAPI({
                operation: "searchCatalogItems",
                endpoint: "catalogItems",
                marketplaceIds: ["A1PA6795UKMFR9"],
                identifiers: eanNumbers,
                identifiersType: "EAN",
            });
            console.log(res);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    })();
}

module.exports = apiCall;

I tried different numbers (all of them in the amazon documentation) and other formats in the marketplaceIds field such as JSON Arrays, Strings and JavaScript Arrays with strings.

That's definitely a valid marketplace ID (A1PA6795UKMFR9 is DE). You can also see the "invalid marketplace ID" error when the merchant you're calling for is not registered in the marketplace's region (in this case EU).

Make sure you are using correct marketplace id. This is my correct working code:

    require("dotenv").config();
    const SellingPartnerAPI = require("amazon-sp-api");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const path = require("path");
    var bunyan = require("bunyan");
    var log = bunyan.createLogger({ name: "node" });
    
    /*
     * Configure logging error or bunyan logger
     */
    const logFilePath = path.join(__dirname, "error.log");
    const logger = new console.Console({
      stdout: fs.createWriteStream(logFilePath, { flags: "a" }),
      stderr: fs.createWriteStream(logFilePath, { flags: "a" }),
    });
    
    /*
     * AmazonOrders Class which used for fetching filtering order data
     */
    class AmazonOrders {
      /*
       * Created constructor for credentials and condition for verifying
       */
      constructor() {
        this.credentials = {
          clientId: process.env.LWA_APP_ID,
          clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
          refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
          aws_access_key_id: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
          aws_secret_access_key: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
          role: process.env.ROLE_ARN,
        };
        this.verifyCredentials();
        this.sellingPartner = new SellingPartnerAPI({
          region: "eu",
          refresh_token: this.credentials.refreshToken,
          credentials: {
            SELLING_PARTNER_APP_CLIENT_ID: this.credentials.clientId,
            SELLING_PARTNER_APP_CLIENT_SECRET: this.credentials.clientSecret,
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: this.credentials.aws_access_key_id,
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: this.credentials.aws_secret_access_key,
            AWS_SELLING_PARTNER_ROLE: this.credentials.role,
          },
        });
      }
    
      verifyCredentials() {
        const missingCredentials = Object.keys(this.credentials).filter(
          (key) => !this.credentials[key]
        );
        if (missingCredentials.length) {
          logger.error(`Missing credentials: ${missingCredentials.join(", ")}`);
          throw new Error(`Missing credentials: ${missingCredentials.join(", ")}`);
        }
      }
    
      /*
       * getOrder method used sp api functions for getting orders details
       */
      async getOrder(
        marketplaceIds,
        lastUpdatedAfter,
        orderStatuses = ["PartiallyShipped", "Unshipped"],
        maxResultsPerPage = 100
      ) {
        try {
          logger.log(
            `Fetching orders from Amazon API for marketplace: ${marketplaceIds}...`
          );
          let params = {
            MarketplaceIds: marketplaceIds,
            LastUpdatedAfter: lastUpdatedAfter,
            // OrderStatuses: orderStatuses,
            MaxResultsPerPage: maxResultsPerPage,
          };
    
          let allOrders = [];
          let nextToken = null;
    
          do {
            /*
             * Used nextToken for pagination
             */
            if (nextToken) {
              params.NextToken = nextToken;
            }
            /*
             * Use node js npm sp api methods
             */
            const response = await this.sellingPartner.callAPI({
              operation: "getOrders",
              endpoint: "orders",
              query: params,
            });
    
            const orders = response.Orders;
    
            // console.log(response);
    
            allOrders = allOrders.concat(orders);
            nextToken = response.NextToken;
            /*
             * Printing out orders data into pretty format with stringify
             */
            const ordersJson = JSON.stringify(allOrders, null, 4);
            console.log(`Order Data : ${ordersJson}`);
            logger.log(`Order Data : ${ordersJson}`);
    
            /*
             * If condition true ordersImport method will start
             */
    
            // console.log(`Count of orders: ${orders.length}`);
            if (orders.length > 0) {
              await this.ordersImport(orders);
            }
          } while (nextToken);
        } catch (error) {
          logger.error(
            `Exception occurred for marketplace ${marketplaceIds}: ${error.message}`
          );
        }
      }
    
    (async () => {
      /*
       * Creating instance of class AmazonOrders()->fetcher
       */
      const fetcher = new AmazonOrders();
      /*
       * Adding Germany and France marketplaces for fetching orders
       */
      const marketplaceIds = ["A1F83G8C2ARO7P", "A1PA6795UKMFR9"];
      /*
       * Logic for fetching data from now to 3 days
       */
      const lastUpdatedAfter = new Date(
        new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 3)
      ).toISOString();
    
      /*
       * Calling instances of amazonorder class method getOrder and adding two parameters
       */
      await fetcher.getOrder(marketplaceIds, lastUpdatedAfter);
      /*
       * Commented code for multiple function to run which is independent
       */
      // await Promise.all([fetcher.getOrder(marketplaceIds, lastUpdatedAfter)]);
    })();

